# Error compiling the compiler GCC

Tags: gcc, makefile, centos, centos5, gcc4

I know, it's an irony to compile a compiler. But I need a specific version of this compiler, and the CentOS 5.x repositories have not the most recent versions of GCC.

The version what i need is 4.3.2 but I only have 4.1.1.

I followed this tutorial to install the gcc http://www.mjmwired.net/resources/mjm-fedora-gcc.html and I used the following parameters at configure (before compiling):

> /root/gcc/gcc-4.3.6/configure --prefix=/opt/gcc43 --program-suffix=43 --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --disable-checking --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-multilib

The last option `--disable-multilib` save me for a another error that I got in previous compile tries (after a long compiling time...)

Also i set an enviroment variable, because in previous tries, i got errors, so i set as following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

That ensure the compiler to search mpfr and gmp libraries (which are needed) in that directory

So, i execute the 'make' command.

I though it was everything ok, because this time took more time (in my last try before setting that variable took me around 2 hours compiling)

I used a Micro instance in Amazon Web Services, this instance only have 1 single core x86_64 processor and 613 MB of RAM, **so it took about 9 HOURS to compile.**

Unfortunetly, i got errors again!!, now I got this:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/gcc/build'
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/gcc/build'
rm -f stage_current
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc/build'
Comparing stages 2 and 3
warning: ./cc1-checksum.o differs
warning: ./cc1plus-checksum.o differs
Bootstrap comparison failure!
./gcc.o differs
./varasm.o differs
./except.o differs
./i386.o differs
make[2]: *** [compare] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc/build'
make[1]: *** [stage3-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/gcc/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "I know, it's an irony to compile a compiler." The technical term is  *bootstrapping* rather than irony.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You likely didn't clean up properly in-between tries. Do a `make distclean` and try again. Sorry.

Comment: The "bootstrapping" worked after distclean, however, i discovered that was a waste of time, because i was using a wrong version of CentOS and   i also found repositories with the packages that i need. Anyway, I prefer to say that I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably grab the .src.rpm for e.g. Fedora 16 and do an rpmbuild ---rebuild on it. If there are any funky Red Hat / CentOS / Fedora flags to worry about, that should handle it. (I'm assuming that there isn't an EPEL RPM already for the version you want?)